# how can I verify response against a predefined json schema in karate?

Tags: json, testing, karate

Currently for checking answer response IO use below method:

```
And match response ==
"""
  {
    "status":#number,
    "message":#string
  }
"""
```

Is there any way to do like below?

```
And match response == someJsonSchemaDefinedInKarateConfigFile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, refer to the documentation on [reading files](https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files).

```
And match response == read('my-schema.json')
```

(edit): There was a comment requesting how to initialize these in `karate-config.js`

`karate-config.js` is intended for 'global' config, I really don't recommend dumping schemas here unless you are sure it will be used by almost all of your tests. But if you are reading from a file, it might be ok as it won't be a time consuming operation, remember `karate-config.js` is re-loaded for *every* `Scenario`.

Within `karate-config.js` you can easily load a JSON or JS file by using `karate.read()`. This should answer your question:

```
function() {
  var config = {

  };
  config.mySchema = karate.read('classpath:my-schema.json');
  return config;
}
```

Comment: I want to put json schema in karate-config.js

Comment: that wasn't clear in your original question :\ anyway, I have edited my answer please confirm.

Comment: this works, but another problem occurred, that must be asked in another place